# Strange electrical noise from stepper motor

Tags: arduino, motor, noise, stepper-motor

[image]It's my first project using arduino. Simply trying to rotate three identical stepper motors, using three 293d h-bridges.

Although it does work properly (meaning the motors do rotate as they should), after the second or third rotation, they start to make a whirring electrical noise -when not moving.

I have attached a schematic of my circuit. The power supply is 5v dc 16A (old computer psu).

You can see exactly what I am experiencing on this video I made (try to listen in closely).

[Video with noise.](https://youtu.be/48YSFqDRraw)

Update: I checked by touching the h-bridges at the same time the noise starts, and I can feel them getting really hot.

Comment: A circuit diagram would be better than a video and infinitely better than the cartoon diagram you have embedded into your question.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to draw the circuit diagram the best I could come up with is the above diagram. As for the video it is the only way for someone to listen to the noise I am talking about. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Seems to be ok now

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the arduino from the drivers after the noise starts?

Comment: Fritzing can create schematic drawings from your design.

Comment: everything stops if I disconnect the arduino. My best guess is that the bridges overheat. Will probably try a different driver and see.

Comment: ok @JRE done (first time user)

Comment: I meant disconnecting the signaling, but keeping the drivers powered. What happens if you disconnect the steppers from the drivers after the noise begins?

Comment: the noise stops

Comment: My guess is that you hear noise from either your supply or PWM used to control the motor current. If you don't use PWM and leave one or both coils energized, you will experience maximum current when the motor is not turning, which might heat your drivers. The maximum current specified in the data sheet is likely only valid if you use a heat sink. If you do use PWM to reduce the holding current (you likely should), you might also hear the PWM frequency, so raise it into ultrasonic range (I.e. above 25 kHz)

Answer (score 1):

What you're hearing is the effect of actually stepping the current. A sharp change in current produces a sharp change in the forces acting on the motor structure, which produces a certain amount of acoustical output. It's not quite the same as hitting it with a hammer (it's a step, not a pulse) but the idea is the same.

If you listen closely, you'll realize that the pitch of the sound you hear is determined by the stepping rate of your driver. If you vary the step rate, the pitch will change as well. The effect is not "pure", since the excitation (a step) produces lots of harmonics.

If you replace your steppers with a pair of sine wave drivers, 90 degrees out of phase, you can get rotation which is essentially silent.

Comment: Thank you, but wouldn't that be the case if the noise was heard when the motor was asked to rotate? Instead the sound is only audible in between the motor rotations

Comment: Sorry, but did you mean the very high-pitched stuff? If so, I have no idea. At first playback I couldn't hear it at all, so I figured it was the stepping noise you were talking about.

Comment: if you turn up the volume you should be able to hear it in the second half of the video